# Why people say "emacs is good for writing lisp program because it's written in emacs lisp"?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I can imagine that IDEs like eclipse written in java are good for writing java program because the tool and the language are tightly integrated. So if some one would say "emacs is good for writing emacs lisp programs" then it would make sense in the same way to me.

But people say emacs is good for all lisp dialects, as if all lisp dialects and emacs are tightly integrated naturally. Not just emacs lisp, not any language, not any langauge use repl, but all lisp dialects. Why? Is there anything in emacs lisp that is shared between all lisp dialects but not really in other languages -- including all these using repl, that is so unique that only lisp dialects could benefit from this? Could you come up with some examples?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and could be moved to Programmers.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that there's little reason that Emacs would have any technical benefit as a generic Lisp environment.  It's not completely zero though -- since Emacs has support that makes it easy to parse most lisps, since their surface syntax (S-expressions) are usually very similar.  But this is still just a technicality.

The real reason is that Emacs comes from times when there was much less variance among lisps (in the syntax sense, semantics is a different issue), so it was basically the only choice of a sophisticated Lisp editing environment.  As such, it enjoys the benefits of literally decades of Lispers who used it for Lisp editing and therefore it was always one of its stronger points -- and on the other hand very few Lispers chose other editors so they suffered from the natural lack of need.  (IIRC, up until not too long ago even vi-clones had little more than basic paren matching.)

More than that, even these days there's a strong relationship since reading elisp is much easier for your J Random Lisper, so they are still the crowd that finds it easy to extend Emacs.  You could make the exact same point for Java & Eclipse, of course -- both are examples of tools that are very extensible, and therefore are very entrenched in their respective communities.

When it gets to executing code, with most lisps (= all except elisp) the work is done in a subprocess so it's no different than using any other editor -- technically speaking.